# SO(3) monopole Floer homology

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, gauge-theory

From what I understand about work on the Witten conjecture relating Donaldson and Seiberg-Witten invariants, the main strategy has been to relate them with the use of the "SO(3) monopole" theory developed by Feehan and Leness (see their paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5085.pdf)).

Both the Donaldson invariants and the Seiberg-Witten invariants have closely related Floer homologies for $3$-manifolds.

Is it possible to define such a Floer homology for $SO(3)$ monopoles? Are there clear reasons that this may or may not be possible?

As a first step, I am curious about whether there is a natural Chern-Simons-like functional $\mathcal{L}$ such that $SO(3)$ monopoles on a cylinder $\mathbb{R} \times Y$ correspond to negative gradient flowlines of $\mathcal{L}$.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that not much work has been done for $SO(3)$ monopoles on three-manifolds. As far as I know, nobody has yet defined a Floer homology for that. However, Feehan, Leness and Kutluhan have started to investigate that, see section 3 of
https://www.math.ias.edu/files/feehanreport.pdf . 
They don't seem to be interested in constructing an $SO(3)$ monopole homology, but they have worked on some issues crucial to developing such a theory (finding appropriate perturbations, solving compactness issues and studying the structure of the flow lines).

They say that $SO(3)$ monopoles on $\mathbb{R} \times Y$ correspond to the gradient flow lines of the $U(2)$ Chern-Simons-Dirac functional. If I am not mistaken, it is just the $U(2)$ Chern-Simons functional plus the usual spinor contribution (pairing between $\Phi$ and $D_B \Phi$).